# Proof of $G=N\rtimes H$ iff $G=NH$ and $N\cap H=\{1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following definition of a semi-direct product:

> Let $G$ be a group. Suppose $N\triangleleft G$ and $H<G$ such that every element of $G$ can be uniquely written $g=nh$. Then $G$ is the semi-direct product of $N$ and $H$.

I have to prove the following lemma:

> Let $N \triangleleft G$ and $H<G$. Then $G=N\rtimes H$ if and only if $G=NH$ and $N\cap H = \{1\}$.

The part I'm having trouble with is using the fact that $G = N \rtimes H$ to imply that $N\cap H=\{1\}$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The construction of $N\rtimes H$ I'm familiar with has the underlying set of $N\rtimes H$ the same as $N\times H$ (but with a more complicated multiplication), so $N\cap H=1$ should be relatively apparent: observe $(n,1)=(1,h)$ holds iff $n,h=1$, meaning a point in the intersection is the identity.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I'm still a bit confused because my lecture notes don't mention N X H when describing semi-direct product. Is there a nice way to prove this using just the following definition of a semi-direct product:
Let G be a group. Suppose N <| G and H < G such that every element of G can be uniquely written g = nh. Then G is the semi-direct product of N and H

Comment: If $g\in N\cap H$ then $g$ can be written as both $g\cdot1$ and $1\cdot g$: these are two different ways of writing $g$ in the form $nh$ with $n\in N,h\in H$... unless $g=1$.

Comment: Thank you! I thought this at first but then I over-thought myself into thinking the order the identity appears in a product doesn't matter.