# Given group $G$, $N \triangleleft G$, $H < G$ prove that $G = N\rtimes H$ iff $f:H\rightarrow G/N, f(h)=hN$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given group $G$, $N \triangleleft G$, $H < G$ prove that $G = N\rtimes H$ iff $f:H\rightarrow G/N, f(h)=hN$ is an isomorphism.

If I assume that $G=N\rtimes H$ then I've proved that $f$ is a homomorphism (direct result from the fact that $N$ is normal), and I've proved that it's injective by proving that $f(h_1)=f(h_2)\iff h_1h_2^{-1}\in N$, which implies that $h_1h_2^{-1}=e$, therefore $h_1=h_2$. I'm stuck on the proof of surjectivity - given $gN \in G/N$ how can I find an $h$ such that $f(h)=gN$?

By assuming that $f$ is an isomorphism I'm stuck on the proof that $H\cap N = \{e\}$ and that $G = N\cdot H$.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478809/proof-of-g-n-rtimes-h-iff-g-nh-and-n-cap-h-1?rq=1).

Comment: In general $h_1h_2^{-1}\in N$ doesn't imply $h_1h_2^{-1}=e$

Comment: @janmarqz It does if $N\cap H = \{e\}$

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\;f:H\to G/N\;,\;\;f(h):=hN\;$ is an isomorphism, then:

$$\begin{align}&\;x\in N\cap H\;\implies f(x):=xN=N\iff x=1\;\;\text{(injec.}\;\;f)\\{}\\&\forall\,x\in G\;\exists\,h_x\in H\;\;s.t.\;\; xN=h_xN\implies x\cdot1=h_xn_x\in HN\implies G=HN\;\;\text{(surj.}\;\;f)\end{align}$$

Comment: In the third line, do you mean $\exists h_x \in H$?

Comment: I don't exactly follow the $x\cdot 1 = h_xn_x\in HN$ part, could you elaborate?

Comment: @derek Yes, of course. Thank you, answer edited.

Comment: @derek: $$1\in N\implies x=x\cdot 1\in xN\implies x\in h_xN\;,\;\;\text{and etc.}$$

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I'm still working on the surjectivity proof in the first part, could you offer a hint?

Comment: I don't understand what part do you mean: in my answer, in your question, something else...? What "first part"

Comment: The question is iff, and when assuming that $G = N\rtimes H$ I'm stuck on the proof that $f$ is surjective (detailed in my question).

Comment: But if $\;G=N\rtimes H\;$ , then $$\;\forall x\;\exists!n_x\in N\;,\;\exists ! h_x\in H\;\;\;s.t.\;\;\;x=n_xh_x\implies f(h_x)=xn_x^{-1}N=xN$$and we're done!

Comment: I just realized that you've proved that $G = HN$, but the definition of semiproduct includes $G=NH$.. is $HN=NH$ true?

Comment: Doesn't $x=n_xh_x$ imply that $h_x=n_x^{-1}x$ and not $h_x=xn_x^{-1}$?

Comment: First, we certainly have $\;HN=NH\;$ as this is a necessary *and sufficient* condition for the product of two subgroups to be a subgroup again, and it is fulfilled if one of the subgroups is normal. Second: for this reason, it doesn't mattekr whether you take $\;h_x=n_x^{-1}x=xn'\;,\;\;n'\in N\;$, though you're formally right.